# Print only a certain amount of statements every second in Java

Tags: java, loops, time, while-loop

I have a while loop that prints a statement indefinitely but I want to
make sure the statement only gets printed a maximum of a certain number of times every second.

What I tried doing was to add a `Thread.sleep(1000 / maxMessagesPerSecond)` after every print statement in the while loop but I'm not sure if it's the most efficient way or if it works all the time.

Comment: Your solution slows down the entire application to N times per second. That's fine as long as the sleep time is greater than or equal to 5 milliseconds.  If you want your application to run faster, you create an output spool (`java.util.List`) and select N rows from the end of the spool to print every second.  You have to manage the spool and delete old rows so it doesn't grow indefinitely.

Comment: Check out Guava's RateLimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works and could be an acceptable solution.

However consider following:

1. Execute that code in an appropriate thread. Details depends on what your application is. Just remember that while in a loop that thread wouldn't do anything else.
2. With `1000 / maxMessagesPerSecond` you get a floor-rounded value. So you could get more than `maxMessagesPerSecond` messages per second.
3. If you a looking for a hight precision, remember that you would get an accumulating error: printing the message takes some time. So each following print would happen in with a bit higher period than `1000 / maxMessagesPerSecond`. In a long run this tiny lags could end with a noticeable deviation.
4. Consider using `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate()`